# innerHTML not showing for IE and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In other browsers, FireFox4, Safari 5, Chrome on both MacX and Win7 ,
my code below works like intented.

only for ie8 en opera is not working...
what do i need to add or change to make it work for those 2 browser too?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".myButton").live("click", function() {               
        $("#myDiv").fadeIn("fast")

        var alertMessage = document.getElementById("alertMessage");     
        var itemName = $(this).parent().find(".itemName").text();
        var itemQuantity = parseInt($(this).siblings(".itemQuantity").val()); 

        alertMessage.innerHTML = itemQuantity + "x " + '<strong>'+itemName+'</strong>' ; 

        $("#myDiv").fadeOut(4000);
    });

});
```

Comment: what element is `alertMessage`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the html using jQuery. Instead of

```
var alertMessage = document.getElementById("alertMessage");     
...
alertMessage.innerHTML = itemQuantity + "x " + '<strong>'+itemName+'</strong>' ;
```

Do:

```
$("#alertMessage").html(itemQuantity + "x " + '<strong>'+itemName+'</strong>') ;
```

Jquery will handle browser differences better.

Comment: Hi Ariel, thanks for the answer. that seems to help. 
the itemName and itemQuantity are not showing in IE only (no values). do you know by any chance what I need to change in those for IE? thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ariel, I solved the issue now. It seems that live click function for ie is interferring in someway with something, so change into to live mouseup function instead, and all seems to work again : )